# Getting error in upgrading angular from v12 to v13 [ ngx-img-cropper]

Tags: angular, npm

I have upgraded my web-app to angular v13 from angular v12 and while serving the application I am getting an error in terminal. This error is related to ngx-img-cropper. The reason for this error according to my understanding is incompatibility of npm `ngx-img-cropper` with Angular v13.

[image]

I have tried out changing the version of the npm package `ngx-img-cropper` to 11.0.0.
I have also tried changing the typescript version to 4.5.4. But it still shows the same error. Can someone tell me how to resolve this error .

Comment: Maybe stop using relative import? Just `'ngx-img-cropper/lib/...'`

Comment: Typically we prefer pasted code over a screenshot and if possible, can you provide a little more info?

Comment: ngx-img-cropper is working fine (in the version 14.0.1) with Angular 16 - check your project setup or share more information about it.